# I need a tree dump option, which doesn't exist any more in current gcc versions

Tags: c++, c, gcc, compiler-construction

Older versions of GCC (for example 4.0.2 or 4.1.2) had the option `-df` (see [*Options for Debugging Your Program or GCC* for 4.1.2](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.1.2/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-fdump_002drtl_002dcfg-357)). I used this option to dump the files `filename.c.134r.life2` and `filename.c.126r.life1`, because I want to extract some values out of these files (for example the register count for every method).

The problem is, that in current versions of GCC (for example, 4.2.2) this option doesn't exist any more. There are other options and the tree dump with the name `filename.c.135r.jump` is pretty much the same. But the register count is missing in this dump, too and I couldn't find a dump which has that values.

Is there still a parameter, which gives me the old dumps in current GCC versions?

Comment: GCC team does such things. I used to use `-fdump-tree-fixupcfg-lineno` option in 4.2, but it's gone in 4.4 :(

Comment: Thanks for good question! Now I know a little more about gcc and its dump options. And cross-reference method of studying sources is the best.

Comment: Re *"in current versions of GCC (for example 4.2.2"*: Do you mean 4.4.2? Option `-df` *was* still [in the documentation for version 4.3.6](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.3.6/gcc/Debugging-Options.html#index-df-499) (released 2011-06-27). It was removed [in the documentation for GCC 4.4](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.4.7/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) (released 2010-04-14). (Note the overlapping release dates - the 4.3 series was not stopped when 4.4 was released.)

Comment: Is the documentation out of sync with the software?

Comment: On the referenced page (4.1.2), "`-df`" is listed just above "`-fdump-rtl-life`" and "`-fdump-rtl-cfg`"  (they are all in the same block).

Comment: Using a development version of 4.4 could explain it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC 4.2-4.3 does really have the `dump_flow_info` function, which reports number of register used.

I'll search, how it can be called. Oh, yes:

```
gcc-4.3.1 file.c -fdump-rtl-all-all
```

produces

```
file.c.175r.lreg
```

with

```
file.c.175r.lreg:81 registers.
```

More specific option: `-fdump-rtl-lreg-all`. It was wested with 4.3.

Comment: dump_flow_info ... dump_options "details", TDF_DETAILS

Comment: For any gcc you can try to find option by `-fdump-rtl-all-all` and `-fdump-tree-all-all` then `grep " registers." file.c.*` to find phase.

Comment: And for newer gcc the set is `-fdump-rtl-all-all -fdump-tree-all-all -fdump-ipa-all-all`.

Comment: And for llvm (just because it is popular too) `-print-after-all` - for llc; or `-mllvm -print-after-all` for clang.

Comment: Agreed. It [seems to have been removed in 4.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161567/i-need-a-tree-dump-option-which-doesnt-exist-any-more-in-current-gcc-versions#comment131117190_2161567) (released 2010-04-14).

Answer (score 1):

Citing the page you gave:

```
[the dump options are] used for debugging the RTL-based passes of the compiler.
```

You should investigate their new plug-in infrastructure. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, you would be in far better position than parsing debug log not meant to bring you the information you want.

Comment: Plugins are available only in GCC 4.5, which in not GA yet

Comment: @qrdl: I've never before seen the term "general availability" applied to GCC, which is non-commercial with open development...

Comment: @ephemient I see what you mean. Valid point. By GA I meant the official stable release. According to GCC homepage, latest stable release (or current release, as they name it) is 4.4.3, although 4.5.0 with plugin support is in active development.