# How to generate control flow graphs for C code 

Tags: gcc, control-flow

Are there any libraries readily available with the gcc compiler?

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1245979/c-c-call-graph-utility-for-windows-platform

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to make gcc spit out a mapping from flow graphs to source code line numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/697817/how-to-make-gcc-spit-out-a-mapping-from-flow-graphs-to-source-code-line-numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Checked `cflow`?